# UIButton tag fetching last update value

Tags: ios, sqlite, tags, uibutton, nsmutablearray

I need to create multiple buttons in UIWebView. So, i used tag for button. And i save the button tag to database with INTEGER . But it's not saving proper value. Each button tag having text in database. Later i need to retrieve. But after storing last value to database and click anyother button it fetching only last updated value. Why this happen?

Table:

```
textnotes          text_id   button_id

  hi                1         1
  how are you       1         3
im fine             2         7
  This is test       2         11
```

UIButton:

```
int gTag = 1;
webviewbutton.tag = gTag;
 gTag++;

[wbCont.scrollView  addSubview:webviewbutton];
```

Insert:

```
const char *sqlInsert = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into textnote (textnotes,text_id,button_id ) values ('%@','%@','%ld')", txtview.text,artID,(long)webviewbutton.tag] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Retrieve button tag with text from database:

```
    textArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        webbutton_art=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        webbutton_button=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    const char *sql =  [[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                     @"SELECT textnotes,text_id,button_id FROM textnote where button_id = '%ld' AND text_id = '%@' ",(long)webviewbutton.tag,artID]cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


                NSLog(@"sql is %s",sql);

                sqlite3_stmt *statement;

                if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

                    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                        txtstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                     (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];


                        webbutton_textartid = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1);

                        webbutton_buttontag= sqlite3_column_int(statement, 2);

          [textArray addObject:txtstring];

         [webbutton_art addObject:@(webbutton_textartid)];

                        [webbutton_button addObject:@(webbutton_buttontag)];


    if( webbutton_art  && webbutton_button ){

    for(int i=0;i<[textArray count];i++){


txtview = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,568)];

        txtview.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];


             txtview.text=[textArray objectAtIndex:i];

 [self.view addSubview:txtview];

             }



    }
```

Comment: first thing is check the tags again

Comment: I didn't get. How? Is i need to change code inside retrieve?

Comment: log them to see values you are getting use break point to check, standard, i think its a small thing missing which only a thorough review will revel

Comment: **int gTag = 1;**  I hope you are initialising at every time , It doesn't get incrementing ...

Comment: or(int i=0;i<[textArray count];i++){

         txtview.text=[textArray objectAtIndex:i];


         }

        [self.view addSubview:txtview];

}
what is this why you always taking last value of array on textview?

Comment: I think your last for loop is not good

Comment: @KumarKI: It increasing. see the button_id increasing 1,3,7,11

Comment: @amar: Yes last loop is wrong. Yes that code take always last value. I know this is wrong. But how to write correct code?

Comment: Take multiple text fields not one. One way is to initialise them and add them on view inside loop

Comment: I used multiple text field with tag. But the button_id (tag) is not string proper. that's why i can't use [textArray objectAtIndex:0] for textview 0 & [textArray objectAtIndex:1] for textview 1. How to get?

Comment: Initialize txtview in the loop, which will create multiple txtview and also keep on adding them self.view with in the loop. This will do the job for you

Comment: @DeepK: I initialize the textview inside loop. But it takes last values only. why?

Answer (score 0):

Declare an integer variable like:

```
int offset;
```

and then do like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<[textArray count]; i++) {



        UITextView *txtview = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100+offset,320,568)];

        txtview.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];


        txtview.text=[textArray objectAtIndex:i];

        [self.view addSubview:txtview];

        offset = offset + 50;
    }
```

Comment: Is need to gTag variable? Because gTag variable used for some other purpose also.

Comment: Did you add the offset?

Comment: You better do one thing send over your code to me and I will fix this for you

Comment: can you give ur mail id

Comment: d.khiwani92@gmail.com